# Prevent UINavigationBar popViewController animation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have the following problem: I have overridden `popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated` of `UINavigationController` because I would like to have a custom animation. The code is as follows:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    UIViewController *poppedCtrl = [super popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [((customViewController *) self.topViewController) doCustomAnimation];
    return poppedCtrl;
}
```

Unfortunately the `UINavigationBar` seems to ignore that I explicitly disable the built in animation and it is still animated.

What do I have to do to also prevent the animation of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some reading and also some experimentation I finally found out what needs to be done to achieve the desired behavior.

To prevent the navigation bar from being animated it is not sufficient to override `(UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`.

It is also necessary to create a custom navigation bar and override `(UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated`:

```
- (UINavigationItem *)popNavigationItemAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    return [super popNavigationItemAnimated:NO];
}
```

Of course this custom navigation bar must also be the one which is used (I just replaced the navigation bar which is used by my navigation controller in the interface builder).

Comment: any reason why this behaviour doesn't also work for pushNavigationItem: ... ?

Comment: Nice work!  I noticed that the back button still fades out in iOS 7 - any thoughts on how to transition instantly?

Answer (score 1):

If anyones looking to disable push animation - this works for me, by overrideing this method on UINavigationBar:

```
- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    NSMutableArray* items = [[self items] mutableCopy];
    [items addObject:item];
    self.items = items;
}
```