# iOS: Removing UINavigationBar animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Our app has an UINavigationBar with an image on it.  When we segue (push) to another screen then click the back button the image on the Navigation Bar seems to animate from left to right as it reappears.  This is a little distracting.  How can you remove this back button animation?

We tried changing the segue Animates setting but this changes both the push animation and not the back animation.

Our Nav Bar code:

```
    let logoImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "ABC")!
    viewController.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: logoImage)
```

Comment: if you know objective-c just a little this answer might help you [How to prevent animation of UINavigationBar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8602982/6689101)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out in large part due to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8602982/47281

Create a custom Nav Bar and override `popItem`:

```
class MyNavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func popItem(animated: Bool) -> UINavigationItem? {
        return super.popItem(animated: false)
    }
}
```

Entered `MyNavigationBar` as the Navigation Bar class for our Navigation Controller via the Storyboard:

[image]

Note I did not override NavigationController `popViewControllerAnimated` as in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is this not working if I do the same with pushItem?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let logoImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "ABC")!
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: logoImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backBtnPressed))
}
```

And then create a method to handle the tap on the button

```
func backBtnPressed(){
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
}
```

Comment: This is not how you replace the back button